# One row (of users) assign to many rows in different tables and databases - mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database, row

Having one table with users (which are registered) in mysql

I simply want to assign every each of them any of the rows in different tables and different tables in other databases.

I though about create for every user stand-alone table with links to this rows.

For example:

> Table my_user  // With two columns
>
> id_of_table     id_of_row

But I afraid is not good solution.

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a user_id column to all the tables you want them for? If you need a central place where you can look up all the tables that are user owned you can either do it by naming convention (prepend "user_owned" or something) or create a tables that has the tables names of all the user owned tables.

Comment: +1 for foreign keys, creating as many tables as there is new users (1 milj or more?) doesn't sound good design solution when that table purpose is to do exactly what foreign keys is meant to be used for.

Comment: So you say that creating new tables for every user is good idea ?

Comment: no, I exactly said that it is bad idea, use foreign keys instead :)

Comment: Yes. But is it mean that i will have table with all users and their words? And have many many times repeated the same user_id ?  And what about the speed of searching of this solution ?

Comment: You can reference the id of the user in a table in another database. There isn't any formal support for cross database foreign keys, but since there isn't any support for foreign keys in MySQL anyway, theres no real downside...

Comment: If you index the user_id field in the tables, searching should be fast.

Comment: Even with 50,000,000 rows ? Linking to the other table ?